# SSH using Elastic Load Balancing Name (Amazon ELB)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to SSH using the name of my application's ELB?

For example:

- App name is "test"
- ELB name is "my-test-loadbalancer"
- ELB DNS name is `myLB-1234567890.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

I want to SSH like SSH test but it’s not working, although a ping test works.

Comment: Try to add the EC2 details in host file and try to SSH using test and make sure you are using correct PPK file.

Comment: Is your ELB configured to forward traffic on TCP port 22 (SSH)?